# GitHub Actions concurrency deadlock

Tags: github-actions

I have two workflows in my repository, `test` and `deploy`:

- `test` runs during pushes, and calls `deploy` as an reusable-workflow.
- `deploy` can be called from other workflows, and also can be triggered manually.

Both use `concurrency` to cancel pending jobs in case new commits are added while a job is running.

However when I execute `test`, I get this message:

```
Canceling since a deadlock for concurrency group 'test-refs/heads/master' was detected between 'top level workflow' and 'deploy'
```

Here are the files:

```yaml
name: test

on:
  push:
  workflow_dispatch:

concurrency:
  group: ${{ github.workflow }}-${{ github.ref }}
  cancel-in-progress: true  

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:          
      - name: Run tests
        run: echo tests
      
  deploy:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/deploy.yml
```

```yaml
name: deploy

on:
  workflow_call:
  workflow_dispatch:

concurrency:
  group: ${{ github.workflow }}-${{ github.ref }}
  cancel-in-progress: true  

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:          
      - name: Deploy
        run: echo deploying
```

First time I saw this I figured I understood the problem: `deploy` was executing in the context of `test`, so it was evaluating to the same concurrency group. Not ideal, I would expect the `deploy` workflow running as a job in `test` would ignore the `deploy.concurrency` and use `test.concurrency` instead, as it is being executed inside `test`, but thought "OK".

Then I explicitly set `test.jobs.deploy.concurrency` to this:

```yaml
name: test

on:
  push:
  workflow_dispatch:

concurrency:
  group: ${{ github.workflow }}-${{ github.ref }}
  cancel-in-progress: true  

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:          
      - name: Run tests
        run: echo tests
      
  deploy:
    concurrency:
      group: ${{ github.workflow }}-${{ github.ref }}-deploy      
      cancel-in-progress: true  
      
    uses: ./.github/workflows/deploy.yml
```

To my surprise I still get the same error:

```
Canceling since a deadlock for concurrency group 'test-refs/heads/master' was detected between 'top level workflow' and 'deploy'
```

One way I could make this work was to delete `deploy.concurrency` altogether, however this is not ideal because I wanted `deploy` to have its own concurrency when triggered manually.

Any suggestions, or perhaps am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This one looks like working by design: https://github.com/github/vscode-github-actions/issues/135
but, for me this also more like a bug, then a feature.